# JSF 2.0 and TransformerFactory

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, saxon, jaxp

I'm going to use Saxon-B 9 in my JSF 2.0 project. But after adding dependency to Saxon & Saxon-dom exceptions began to appear at startup:

> Sep 25, 2010 6:05:45 PM
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
>   info INFO: Logging to
>   JettyLogger(null) via
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
>   Sep 25, 2010 6:05:45 PM
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader
>   readAppEngineWebXml INFO: Successfully
>   processed
>   /home/chardex/projects/metabus/trunk/clients/export/target/articats/export_exploded/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>   Sep 25, 2010 6:05:45 PM
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader
>   readConfigXml INFO: Successfully
>   processed
>   /home/chardex/projects/metabus/trunk/clients/export/target/articats/export_exploded/WEB-INF/web.xml
>   Sep 25, 2010 6:05:45 PM
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
>   info INFO: jetty-6.1.x Sep 25, 2010
>   6:05:46 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>   contextInitialized INFO: Initializing
>   Mojarra 2.0.0 (RC2 b22) for context ''
>   Sep 25, 2010 6:05:48 PM
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager
>   initialize INFO: Unsanitized
>   stacktrace from failed start...
>   **> com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper$ChildEnumeration.isAtomizing()Z**
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:670)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:306)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:219)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:185)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:147)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
>   Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper$ChildEnumeration.isAtomizing()Z
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:668)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper$ChildEnumeration.isAtomizing()Z
>     at
>   net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper$ChildEnumeration.(NodeWrapper.java:1079)
>     at
>   net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper.iterateAxis(NodeWrapper.java:722)
>     at
>   net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.defaultAction(ApplyTemplates.java:375)
>     at
>   net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:333)
>     at
>   net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1807)
>     at
>   net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1621)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:906)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:831)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:787)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:656)
>     ... 25 more Sep 25, 2010 6:05:48 PM
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
>   warnwarn

But I still do not use the library and do not understand why the JSF begins its use it. I tried to delete file javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory from saxon jar, but it did't help.

Comment: It fixes if start with parameter -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory ="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl". But how to set in config files or on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saxon was already in the classpath, but you've apparently added an outdated version to the classpath which is lacking the method as mentioned in the `NoSuchMethodError` message.

Likely Saxon was already among the standard libraries in the classpath. Saxon is one of the JAXP implementations. JSF makes use of JAXP to parse among others the `faces-config.xml` file.

To fix this particular problem, just remove the outdated version of Saxon from the classpath which you've added manually to the classpath and it should work.